# Extending existing menu/route in module_menu_alter

Tags: routes

Trying to extend Rooms (`rooms_booking_manager`):

Originally, there is an enquiry-page which takes arguments

```
"enquiry/[startDate]/[endDate]/[roomNumber]"
```

I want to write a more specific handler IF arguments persons and children are given as in enquiry/startDate/endDate/roomNumber/numberOfPersons/numberOfChildren; in that case my own handler should take precedence.

This is the code used by the module.

```
function rooms_booking_manager_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['enquiry/%start_date/%end_date'] = array(
    'title' => 'Ask about availability',
    'page callback' => 'rooms_booking_manager_enquiry_page',
    'page arguments' => array(1, 2),
    'access arguments' => array('book units'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  // …

  return $items;
}
```

This is the code I use in my module.

```
function netfactory_rooms_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['enquiry/%start_date/%end_date/%persons/%children'] = array(
    'title' => 'Ask about availability',
    'page callback' => 'netfactory_rooms_enquiry_page',
    'page arguments' => array(1, 2, 3, 4),
    'access arguments' => array('book units'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
}
```

Nevertheless, if I call enquiry/startDate/endDate/roomNumber/numberOfPersons/numberOfChildren `rooms_booking_manager_enquiry_page()` is called instead of `netfactory_rooms_enquiry_page()`.

Coming from a .NET MVC background, I was thinking that the order (most specific first) is important; so I also tried setting `weight=-1000` on my own route, but that did not help either.

How can I hook into a module to add a route which is MORE SPECIFIC than an existing route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Drupal, enquiry/%start_date/%end_date/%persons/%children and enquiry/%start_date/%end_date are different; so you aren't overriding an old one, but defining a new one, for which you should use `hook_menu()`, not `hook_menu_alter()`.

You just need to use code similar to the following one.

```
function netfactory_rooms_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['enquiry/%start_date/%end_date'] = array(
    'title' => 'Ask about availability',
    'page callback' => 'netfactory_rooms_enquiry_page',
    'page arguments' => array(1, 2),
    'access arguments' => array('book units'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
}

function netfactory_rooms_enquiry_page($start_date, $end_date, $persons = DEFAULT_VALUE_FOR_PERSONS, $children = DEFAULT_VALUE_FOR_CHILDREN) {
  // …
}
```

(Replace the constants with the values you wish.)

As you read in the first example on [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7), if the page callback is called for abc/def, its parameters will get their default value, while called for abc/def/123/foo, `$ghi` will be `'123'` and `$jkl` will be `'foo'`.

```
  function mymodule_menu() {
    $items['abc/def'] = array(
      'page callback' => 'mymodule_abc_view',
    );
    return $items;
  }

  function mymodule_abc_view($ghi = 0, $jkl = '') {
    // ...
  }
```

Keep in mind that wildcard parameters like %start_date are used if there is a function named `start_date_load()` used to return an array or an object that is then passed to the page callback; if you don't have such function, you should use the generic wildcard %. Then, when the parameter is at the end of the path, and you don't use a load function, then there isn't any need to use wildcard parameters.

Comment: That was the problem - thought I needed named args, but simple '/%' did the job!

Answer (score 1):

I would try `netfactory_rooms_menu()` (i.e. `hook_menu()` instead of `hook_menu_alter()`). You are effectively creating a new menu callback, not extending an existing one.

Also, **CLEAR THE CACHE** before trying the new path.